# Apache server RewriteRule to Tomcat war - Remove application name from url

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, url-rewriting

I'm having problems with RewriteRule. My tomcat application is Xyz and it is placed in its folder on localhost. Server name is www.mydomain.com. Application can be reached with www.mydomain.com/Xyz, but I would like to reach it with www.mydomain.com. Is it possible to achieve this with RewriteRule?

I use JkMount within the Apache configuration file:

```
JkMount /Xyz worker1
JkMount /Xyz/* worker1
```

where worker1 is member of worker defined as:

```
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.lbfactor=1
```

I tried to add to the Apache configuration file RewriteRule just before JkMount:

```
ServerName www.mydomain.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /Xyz/$1 [L,PT]
```

but with no success. Application can be easily reached with www.mydomain.com/Xyz, but www.mydomain.com doesn't work at all. it just produces error message...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy not to use URL rewrite you can achieve similar by defining ROOT context.

Detailed Tomcat Context documentation [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context)

[ Note: didn't try this, will do later ] I'd suggest you move your move application to a directory outside of your /webapps, eg. /myapps/xyz/; and then add a file to define your application context (for Tomcat 7)

```
$CATALINA_HOME$/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
```

for previous Tomcat version probably something like:

```
$CATALINA_HOME$/conf/ROOT.xml
```

In ROOT.xml define where your application root (docBase) is and l*eave path element empty*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
    <Context deployOnStartup="true" docBase="/myapps/xyz/" path="" reloadable="false">
    <Manager pathname=""/>
</Context>
```

Similar posts are here

- [Tomcat 6: How to change the ROOT application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application#2369628)
- [Tomcat mapping context via server.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434964/tomcat-mapping-context-via-server-xml)

Srecno